# Failed to connect Mobile First server using angular

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobile-services

When ever i am trying to connect from device, always i am getting the below error

The connection to the server was unsuccessful

```
fille:///android_asset/www/index.html
```

In appcomponent added the below code.

```
   WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()
        .then(function (accessToken) {
        alert("Connected to MobileFirst Server");
    }, function (error) {
        alert("Failed to connect to MobileFirst Server");
    });
```

I am using angular cordova.

Comment: The application flow never enters the failure call back? If it does, print the contents of the error object. 
alert("Failed to connect.. " + JSON.stringify(error));

Comment: To be clear - it works for you in browser, but not in device? When you say "not in device", does it mean when you deploy the application to the device ? Or from device browser?

Comment: @VivinK, now i am getting , "{"responseHeaders":{},"status":200,"responseText":"undefined","errorCode":"UNRESPONSIVE_HOST","errorMsg":"unresponsive host"}", POST file:///mfp/api/registration/v1/self

Comment: Is the server end point reachable from the device? Find the hostname and port it is it trying to connect to, and see if it is reachable from the device.

Comment: @VivinK, actually server enpoint url will pick automatically from config.xml, in my case why it is not featching form device i am not getting, here my config.xml (    <mfp:server runtime="mfp" url="http://172.20.10.3:9080" />
)

Comment: @VivinK, endpoint url coming like it Request URL: file:///mfp/api/adapters/sampe/sampleProcedure (While trying from device) in angular 7 with cordova with out ionic framework

Comment: Can you please open a case with MFP support? We can debug in more detail with a case.